# Editing titles that use Title Case

Tags: discussion, editing

Should we be editing question titles that capitalise each word?

E.g.

[If David Commited Adultery, How Could He Remain With Bathsheba?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35776/if-david-commited-adultery-how-could-he-remain-with-bathsheba)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that a number of askers prefer title case and a number prefer sentence case. Title case seems to make more sense to me (the question title is the title, after all, of the body of the question), whereas sentence case seems to me to be easier-to-read. Sentence case is certainly grammatical if the title is a sentence, and even all-lowercase is grammatical if it isn't a sentence (and is easy to read). I don't see any reason to change any of these to the another: I think we should respect the original asker's choice. (Not, though, if the original asker's choice is not a normal English choice, like capitalizing only verbs or using all-lowercase for a sentence.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's official guidance on this from SE, but I've noticed that the vast majority of question titles on several sites that I frequent use sentence case rather than title case.  I think there's a reason for that -- title case is usually used with phrases (that might omit "minor" words) while sentence case is used with, you know, actual sentences/questions.  I think (but can't support) that the case affects how we read the affected text.  (This just [came up](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/10399/1993) yesterday on Writers, BTW -- so far anecdotal answers only, but maybe somebody will bring sources later.)

When I'm editing a question anyway I tend to change title case to sentence case.  Whether that alone is a reason to edit is less clear to me; I'd suggest looking to see if there's anything else that could be done at the same time (tags, linking sources, formatting improvements, etc) then do the larger edit.  But if the title case is bothering you and everything else about the question is ok, then I think it's fine to change it *l'hatchilah*.  (Now we'll see if the voters agree with me. :-) )  If the OP objects, though, don't get into an edit war -- bring it up in chat or here.